Does Firestore's FieldValue.serverTimestamp() Guarantee Unique Strong Consistency?
I have some questions regarding the behavior of Firestore's FieldValue.serverTimestamp():

Indexing and Collisions:
I want to rank documents by sorting them using FieldValue.serverTimestamp().
If I create the appropriate indexes, does Firestore's strong consistency model guarantee that these server timestamps will not collide?

High Volume Requests Without Indexes:
In a scenario where there are no indexes, even with strong consistency, if a high volume of FieldValue.serverTimestamp() requests are made simultaneously for different documents, is it possible for the server timestamps to exactly match and thus collide?


I read the Firestore documentation and searched online for details about FieldValue.serverTimestamp()'s precision and consistency guarantees.
I expected to find whether the nanoseconds always end with "0000" and if strong consistency prevents timestamp collisions. However, I couldn't find definitive answers.
Any insights or official documentation references would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

TL;DR: You should not depend on server-side timestamp values being unique.


... If I create the appropriate indexes, does Firestore's strong consistency model guarantee that these server timestamps will not collide?


No.


... is it possible for the server timestamps to exactly match and thus collide?


Yes.
It is quite possible for multiple documents to be created with the same timestamp, and this has nothing to do with the strength of the consistency model that Firestore uses.

Oh, Thanks!!
So, does this mean Firestore is not suitable for large-scale queue or numbering systems? Should I consider Kafka or other systems?

I'm not sure what you mean by that type of system, and have a feeling we started with a XY problem here. If you want to generate unique IDs, use Firestore's built-in add() operations, if you want to have creation timestamps use server-side timestamps for that - but don't conflate those two use-cases. --- Also see What should I do when someone answers my question?

Is the fact that nanoseconds part of server-timestamp always ends with '0000' just a coincidence, or does Firestore actually provide only microsecond-level resolution? Thanks!

I answered two questions from the three in your post. Please include only a single question per post going forward. Also see What should I do when someone answers my question?
